# I have a responsive page and I cant get my drop own menu to center on the smallest window size,

Tags: css, html

I tired setting the anchor display to block and setting max-width on everything to 100%, but this isn't working. shouldnt setting setting the max-width to 100% an making anchor a block element, make everything expand the entire width? Why isn't this working and how can I get it to work? thanks

```css
html {
  font-size: 1em;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
header {
  background-image: url('../img/MountainsTestImage.jpg');
  background: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-title {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
nav li > span,
nav a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
nav li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav:hover {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}
.home-page a:visited {
  color: white;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: orange;
}
nav a,
span {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.active {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}
.main-nav {
  position: relative;
}
.sub-nav li:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.sub-nav {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.sub-nav li {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.sub-nav li a {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav:hover .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}
section {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
footer {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  nav ul {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 5% 0 0;
  }
  .main-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15%;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="main-title">This Is a Test</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="main-nav home-page active">
          <a href="index.html">HOME</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="main-nav">
          <span> Content 1 </span>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-nav">
          <span> Content 2 </span>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-nav">
          <span> Content 3 </span>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 8</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 9</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should put a <style></style> tag inside your <head></head> tag and cut and paste your CSS there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your UL is constraining the width, % is always relative to the parent.

```
.sub-nav {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Should fix it:

https://jsfiddle.net/tvjphz51/1/

Comment: Thanks that seemed to solve my problem. I copy and pasted that css and it works, however I'm a bit confused, I think I already had all the nav children set to 100%  including sub-nav.  Something obviously changed, but I cant find what was changed to fix the problem

Comment: I had all the nav children and the nav set to max-width. My understanding is that max-width is relative to the parents and if  all the parents max width was set to 100%, it should work, so, what am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Yep, that was what was changed. The culprit is the position:absolute on sub-nav. Your understanding is correct for statically positioned block objects, but when you position something absolutely - it is no longer a block level element and no longer tries to fill its parent to 100%. Therefore max-width no longer has any effect. And please set the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Here is how to accept:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work